# WebVPN Software for HTTP tunnel for Windows environment

Tags: windows-10, http, proxy, vpn

I need to use an HTTP service out of my office, usually I use a standard VPN (like OpenVpn) but, considering that I will use only HTTP service, I would like to have a Web-VPN so I can use only my browser without any client or custom connection needed.

I found some firewalls has this feature but I cannot change my hardware, then I'm looking for a software-only solution for a Web-VPN. Does it exist?

I'm not sure, but maybe this kind of software is also called "Reverse Proxy"

Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is :

You can install [Node](https://nodejs.org/en/) on your Windows PC, and then install the Node module [localtunnel.js](https://localtunnel.github.io/www/).

Then run the `lt` command on your command line, and you'll get an URL of your new publicly available website. The URL will be visible in the output of `lt`.

Who gives you that URL?  Localtunnel the company. It's free.

Clarify this with your boss or IT department. Making internal resources available  to the public internet could be a firing offense in some businesses.

Comment: What is the difference between opening the service directly to internet by NAT? I need a secured access SSL with authentication.

Comment: You do not need to register a DNS name, for example.Localtunnel will register the name for you. - You did not say that you want to open a HTTPS connection. Instead you said HTTP originally in your post. -- Anyway, my localtunnel solution is easy, no tinkering required. However it is feasible only for a temporary connection, to have a quick look. For a permanent (secure, high-bandwidth) solution you need something else.

Comment: How DNS is relevant with my question or comment? Your solution seems to be a tunnel, this is not a VPN. A webVPN should be secure and private, how can it be private without authentication? How can be secure without SSL? I confirm my service is HTTP, but this is the service I need through the VPN, not the protocol of the VPN itself.

Comment: Yes it is a tunnel but it seems to me that is what you asked for. (Your post's title currently reads _WebVPN Software for HTTP tunnel for Windows environment_). - I'm done here.

Comment: You have missed just the first word.